# What functionality is available if I pair a (Windows10) laptop to an iMac over bluetooth

Tags: macos, windows-10, bluetooth

I was trying to pair a wireless mouse to a Surface 4(Win10). During the process I noticed my iMac(OSX) in the list of available devices to pair.

Why might I want to pair these two devices, is there some extra functionality.

Comment: You can transfer data over Bluetooth

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for that summary of bluetooth. But my question was about functionality: can I transfer files, can I share screens, can I stream from on to the other?

Comment: You asked, "why might you pair the two devices", I pointed out Bluetooth supports data transferring.  How depends on the OS used.  Data transferring includes transferring files.....

Answer (score 1):

"Why might I want" - this is quite a broad question. Do you want to connect Surface (which is not a laptop) to iMac as a second monitor?

There is no direct data (files) transfer even between iPhone and iMac except for duplicating content - AirPlay. Apple is known to be strict on the policies for data transfer that's why you cannot send photos or music over Bluetooth between iOS devices (there used to be [Bump](http://blog.bu.mp/) back in the days) not mentioned the other devices manufacturers.

You might only be able to control the mouse behaviour (just a guess) or [duplicate the display](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWFyDSSV_HU) (although the last option is not wireless and requires miniDP to miniDP cable).

Comment: point taken, I'll edit the q.